# Sublime Text 2 auto completion popup does not work properly

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I got problem with jQuery Snippet that i installed throughout package control. After installation I do not have popup with jQuery code hints and intalisance. Look at this video:
http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-2/lessons/adding-snippets-through-package-control

On 0:50 after typing <kbd>.</kbd> he got popup with code hints - I don't have this one. I have to type <kbd>.</kbd> on and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to display popup with snippet...
And yes, I'm in JavaScript file and I got default settings.

And after <kbd>.</kbd> he also got all jQuery functions like `add` or `addClass`. I do not have this one even if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Come on guys ? How its on your machine ? Do you have autocompletion when you typing (in real time)(for javascript or jQuery code) just like in above movie ? – born2fr4g just now edit

Comment: i have the same problem. I don't see the autocompletion popup in realtime. `tab` either automatically completed my text (I guess when there is just one match) or shows the popup, which I would like to see in real time!

Comment: see answer below - you can get it manually or set it do do this automatically while you type

Comment: the answer below is the right one...

Comment: This may be a duplicate of "[Getting full JS autocompletion under Sublime Text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13661462/1309332)."

Comment: (which was asked after this question, sorry).

Comment: I've got the same problem. The answer below doesn't help.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you hit CTRL-SPACE you'll get the dropdown of available completions for what you've just typed.

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/tab_completion.html

If you want the autocomplete dropdown to appear as you type then add this line to your User Preferences.sublime-settings file:

```
{
  "auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
}
```

That should do what you're looking for :-)

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately. I'm having the same issue on ST2 on Windows and I'm trying to get those jQuery snippets to run with autocomplete. Just. Doesn't. Work.

Comment: Ok, found the problem! See my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

Consider changing User Settings to the following:

```js
{
  // By default, auto complete will commit the current completion on enter.
  // This setting can be used to make it complete on tab instead.
  // Completing on tab is generally a superior option, as it removes
  // ambiguity between committing the completion and inserting a newline.
  "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,

  // Controls if auto complete is shown when snippet fields are active.
  // Only relevant if auto_complete_commit_on_tab is true.
  "auto_complete_with_fields": true,

  // As Richard Jordan suggested, this item
  // controls what scopes auto complete will be triggered in
  "auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
}
```

> Open your *User Settings* by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on Windows

And if you want to fully grasp Sublime Text 2, I do recommend this course: [Perfect Workflow in Sublime Text](https://tutsplus.com/course/improve-workflow-in-sublime-text-2/). It used to be free by the time I first posted this answer. I still recommend it anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Which OS are you using? I'm guessing Windows.

The problem here seems to be that the jQuery snippets in the available plugins have `<tabTrigger>` attributes that start either with a **$** or a **.**, which causes trouble.

Try the following: Find the jQuery package that contains those snippets (Under *Preferences -> Browse Packages*) and open the .sublime-snippet file of a snippet that doesn't work properly. The one you named in your post would be defined in the file *event-on.sublime-snippet*.

Find the line

```
<tabTrigger>.on</tabTrigger>
```

and remove the **.** as follows

```
<tabTrigger>on</tabTrigger>
```

Save and return to your .js file. Now see if the snippet shows up when you type *o*. This works for me.

I guess this is a bug in Sublime Text 2 for Windows (maybe Linux, too?), since it obviously works fine on OS X as we see in the video course you've linked.

There was an [issue created on GitHub](https://github.com/aaronpowell/sublime-jquery-snippets/issues/6#issuecomment-17679682) on this specific package and I now commented this info. I guess the only way to get this working is to have snippets that do not start with special characters.

I also filed a [bug for Sublime Text on Userecho](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/173733-/).

Answer (score 3):

The creator of the video is using [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel). What you see at 00:50 isn't Sublime Text 2's autocompletion popup, it's SublimeCodeIntel's import autocompletion popup:

> Imports autocomplete - Shows autocomplete with the available modules/symbols in real time.

See [the Github page](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) for more information.