# How can I have autocomplete for python libraries in sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Currently when I import some code, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

I can't see what methods it has. How could I know that there is utcnow() for example. It would be great if there is some plugin for sublime so that I have this functionality , as it is in eclipse with cntr+space for methods. Also may be if there is some navigation between classes definitions , or going to property definition and etc.

[image: Preferences plugins]

Comment: Have you installed any of the Python IDE plugins? Read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12656448/3001761?

Comment: I don't know really. I had followed this tutorial: https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/   and I will add image of the plugins that I have installed

Comment: Why haven't you installed Anaconda, which that tutorial mentions?

Comment: It looks to me too big package with things that I don't need and I searched for other one. Thank you

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can have this functionality with the [**Anaconda Package**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda).

[image]

Anaconda includes a lot more features than just auto completetion. You can install the **[Jedi Package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jedi%20-%20Python%20autocompletion)**. This is the auto complete that ships with Anaconda.

Comment: May be dumb question but I don't see the documentation for the methods. Is there way  in python to see comments for the methods in sublime

Comment: You can do that with the Anaconda package by typing "Anaconda: Display object docs" into the *Command Palette* of Sublime. Press Enter and it'll show.

Answer (score 36):

try [SublimeJEDI](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jedi%20-%20Python%20autocompletion)

step 1:  `ctrl`+`shift`+`p` `search - install package`

step 2: Wait for few seconds until drop down box to appear

step 3: search **Jedi - Python autocompletion** and press enter

now auto completion for python will work in sublime..

**Note:** you can try `Anaconda` instead `Jedi` using same step.

Comment: It's CTRL + '  (not ctrl + shift + p) on my Windows 10 setup  (thats a backquote which is on the same key as my @ symbol on my UK keyboard)

Comment: Just a detail, I needed to restart Sublime3 after installation to get it working on.

Comment: Jedi Python auto-completion is just what I was looking for.  Thank you