# Autocomplete doesn't always show up unless I do control+space in Sublime Text

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Let me start off by saying that I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656448/sublime-text-2-auto-completion-popup-does-not-work-properly) post. The autocomplete window occasionally shows up, but sometimes it doesn't like when I try to get a list of available methods for an object. Here is an example:

As you can see, when I type in some code nothing happens:

[image]

But when I press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, the available methods show up:

[image]

Here are my relevant User settings:

```
{
    "auto_complete": true,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
    "auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following setting to your preferences:

```js
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source, text.html"
    }
]
```

This will make autocomplete appear every time you hit the <kbd>.</kbd> button.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Do you have any idea about why I'm having this issue?

Comment: @saadq I'm not sure. I've had this setting in my User preferences ever since I started using Sublime years ago, so I honestly don't remember what it was like beforehand. I suspect that the autocomplete engine may run a bit slowly, and if it isn't *quite* ready to display when you are, it doesn't display at all. I'm don't know. You can also try checking out [tern_for_sublime](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/tern_for_sublime) that uses the popular TernJS autocomplete engine for JavaScript and Node. Some other languages have different ones, like Anaconda for Python.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks once again.